# How to do placement allocation Eigen::Matrix to Shared Memory (or Heap)?

Tags: c++, memory, shared-memory, eigen, placement-new

I just tried to allocate an instance which contains Eigen::Matrix to Xenomai's shared memory.

```
unsigned char * mem; //shared memory pointer
Robot * robot = new ((void *)(mem+ROBOT_ADDR)) Robot();
```

The Robot class contains several Eigen::Matrix. However, I can't allocate robot object in my shared memory.

But the basic allocation was working well lke below.

```
Robot * robot = new Robot(); //work well!
```

The Assertion log is:

> Eigen::internal::plain_array::plain_array() 
>   [with T = double; int Size = 36; int MatrixOrArrayOptions = 0]: 
>       Assertion `(reinterpret_cast(eigen_unaligned_array_assert_workaround_gcc47(array)) & 0xf) == 0 
>           && "this assertion is explained here: " "http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicUnalignedArrayAssert.html" " 
>           **** READ THIS WEB PAGE !!! ****"' failed.

I already checked the web page in the log. But there is no solution for my case.

How to do placement allocation Eigen::Matrix to Shared Memory (or user-defined specific heap)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the linked webpage:

> fixed-size vectorizable Eigen objects must absolutely be created at 16-byte-aligned locations, otherwise SIMD instructions addressing them will crash.

So the problem is that `mem+ROBOT_ADDR` is not 16-byte aligned.  You need to ensure that it is.

Comment: Another solution is to use unaligned types like: `Matrix<float,4,4,DontAlign>` instead of `Matrix4f`.

Comment: I solved it to use `__attribute__ ((aligned 16))`. Thanks XD